# How to keep attributes with parseFragment in Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon

In Firefox extension we use `parseFragment` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIScriptableUnescapeHTML)) to parse a string of HTML (received from 3rd party server) into a sanitized `DocumentFragment` as it required by Mozilla. The only problem, the parser removes all attributes we need, for example, `class` attribute.

Is it possible somehow to keep `class` attributes while parsing HTML with `parseFragment`?

P.S. I know that in Gecko 14.0 they [replaced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIParserUtils) this function with another which supports sanitizing parameters. But what to do with Gecko < 14.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the whitelist is [hardcoded](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/40455cbb1ad3/content/base/src/nsTreeSanitizer.cpp#l187) and cannot be adjusted. However, the `class` attribute is in the whitelist and should be kept, you probably meant the `style` attribute? If you need a customized behavior you will have to use a different solution (like [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser) which can parse HTML documents in Firefox 12).

As to older Firefox versions, you can parse XHTML data with `DOMParser` there. If you really have HTML then I am only aware of one way to parse it without immediately inserting it into a document (which might cause various security issues): [range.createContextualFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.createContextualFragment). You need an HTML document for that, if you don't have one - a hidden `<iframe>` loading `about:blank` will do as well. Here is how it works:

```js
// Get the HTML document
var doc = document.getElementById("dummyFrame").contentDocument;

// Parse data
var fragment = doc.createRange().createContextualFragment(htmlData);

// Sanitize it
sanitizeData(fragment);
```

Here sanitizing the data is your own responsibility. You probably want to base your sanitization on Mozilla's whitelist that I linked to above - remove all tags and attributes that are not on that list, also make sure to check the links. The `style` attribute is a special case: it used to be insecure but IMHO no longer is given than `-moz-binding` isn't supported on the web any more.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll recheck with `class` (i think it has been removed, but not sure now) ... in any case, yes, `style` is also important. FF12 isn't an option since i need to support FF4+.

Comment: Well, now i understand. What about if i get HTML from the source i trust (my server that generates that html) and put it into DOM with `innerHTML`. Is it violates security in the extension (i just mean, if it is same security level as write custom sanitizer, or Mozilla needs to be sure and they need to see exactly how i sanitize the data)?

Comment: @gakhov: Your server is not a trusted source. The communication with the server might have been modified by an attacker, or your server might be hacked. This shouldn't result in a compromise of user's computer - which is what happens if you insert the data into a privileged document. You might try [this approach](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Displaying_web_content_in_an_extension_without_security_issues#Restricting_what_documents_that_contain_untrusted_data_can_do) as a last resort but sanitizing the data would be preferable.